# Uitextview text is null when not clicking on textview in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5

iam working with UITextView, its delegate methods are calling well when i modify textview and i got text. its working fine. when iam not modify the textview text, i got null value.

```
 NSLog(@"currentTextView.text is %@",currentTextView.text);
 NSLog(@"currentTextView.tag is %d",currentTextView.tag);
```

the currenttextview.tag is 0, but text is null.

i didn't understand what is the problem. but i clearly understand one thing, that is only delegate methods are called when textview is clicked. if it is not clicked, delegates are not called, but where is the previous text, it is null.

Please tell me any suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `text` property of `UITextView` is `nil` by default, not an empty string.

Comment: I saved textview.text for first time, and displaying the same text, then for 2nd time, iam not touching textview and press save button, then i got null value.

Comment: then that's because you're either re-instantiating the text view or losing the pointer to it (or both). Show some code, it's impossible to proceed without.

Comment: [(UITextField*)nil setText:@"a"];
NSLog(@"the value is %@", [(UITextField*)nil text]);

Comment: Try logging `currentTextView` as well (something like `NSLog(@"currentTextView is %@", currentTextView);`)—if `currentTextView` is `nil`, then `currentTextView.text` and `currentTextView.tag` will both be `0`/`nil`/`NULL`.  (I think this might be what iPatel was trying to get at.)

Comment: Can you create a sample app with the textview related code and post it here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set Focus on your TextView when you load your view, it will invoke "- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView" of UITextView

```
[youTextViewObj becomeFirstResponder];
```

Its because delegates are action/events binded with Control, and it will fire on some action on Control, thats why its not returning Nil value without clicking it.